# How do I return form objects that are not null as a receipt?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web application that has about 50 or more fields split up into several panels and I am using them in a `asp:wizard` across several steps. At the end of the form I want to create a "Here is what you requested Label1.text...." according to whatever the user requested without recreating several labels and binding the text of each box to label manualy. Here is what I have tried in attempt to call a list of textboxes that are not null in the form, but it throws an exception because of the exclamation.

```
var requested = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                          .Where(txt => string.!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text));

    foreach (var textBox in requested)
    {
        Response.Write(requested);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Instead of using Response.Write (which can get messy), I would use a single label control. Let's call out lblResult.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var textBox in requested)
{
    sb.Append(textBox.Text); //Add the text not the textbox
    sb.Append("</br>"); //Add a line break to make it look pretty
}
lblResult.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Note the use of StringBuilder to build our resultant string for performance sake.

You will also need to fix your Where clause as per the other answers:

```
Where(txt => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
```

Comment: you have `sb.Append(textbox.Text)`then one for a line break...would I there list all of the textboxes on the form?

Comment: The loop is iterating through the Linq query you constructed and called 'requested'

Comment: I think I see what you did...you forgot to capitalize the other "B" in the `sb.Append`

Comment: I've only started scripting C# webforms last year. Thanks for your help, without this site I would be one lost puppy!

Answer (score 4):

It's because that's invalid syntax - you want to call `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and invert the result:

```
.Where(txt => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
```

Currently you've got the `!` in the middle of the method invocation, which is what's wrong.

(Then be aware that currently you're trying to write out the textbox itself - I suspect you don't want to do that. But you'll find that out when you've got past the syntax error.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)` instead of `string.!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)`

`string.!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)` is an invalid syntax thus you are getting complitation error

Comment: but that will return the empty ones....I want to return the ones that are not empty

Comment: @Skullomania, `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)` will return that are not empty